# How to get current cursor position on console?

Tags: java, console-application

How to get current cursor position on console and write it from same position in next line  ?

For example I want to get the starting position of letter `L` in line2 on console.Then in next line(with `System.out.println`) start from same position. Not sure how to do
it ?

```
Line1
Line2
            Line3
            //Start from here
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be many ways to do it, this just popped first ...

- get position of L in desired line (here Line2) using String indexOf method in a variable called noOfSpaces
- use System.out.println to go to next line
- use System.out.printf to print space noOfSpaces times or use an empty space string of that size so that your cursor will be at same position in current line as L in desired line